# What should be done inside ContentResolver's public constructor call?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

In `ContentResolver` class a public constructor is available. Generally we used to call all the methods by calling `getContentResolver()` method of `Context` and everything works fine. When I call public constructor of `ContentResolver` it needs to be implemented as a inner type. So what should be done there? Is any configuration needed if not then why it is been Inner type.

```
    ContentResolver cr = new ContentResolver(this) {} ;
```

and I cannot call the constructor directly as

```
    ContentResolver cr = new ContentResolver(this);
```

Why is it so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any particular reason for instantiating the `ContentResolver` class?

Comment: not really I was just going through the API reference and tried calling the constructor